# How can I make an alias for this command piping docker-compose logs -f into less?

Tags: linux, bash, less

I have a working command which I would like to make an alias for, but can't seem to figure out how to do.  The working command is

```
docker-compose logs -f | less -S -R +F
```

This works fine, essentially removing word wrap from the logs.

The caveat is that when using this I also want to be able to optionally add arguments to the middle, to specify the particular service(s) to tail.  Making something that end up looking like this

```
docker-compose logs -f service1 service2 etc... | less -S -R +F
```

To be able to do this I was thinking I could use `xargs -I` to pass in a variable number of arguments and inject them into the middle of the command.  But my skill with bash is very limited, and so no matter how much I fiddle with it I can't seem to get it to work, and am sure there is something/some concept I'm missing.

The last iteration of the alias I tried before posting this is

```
alias logsx="xargs -I{} bash -c 'docker-compose logs -f \"{}\" | less -S -R +F'"
```

which when you run it seems to start `less` but without the docker logs being piped there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a function instead.

```
logsx() {
    docker-compose logs -f "$@" | less -S -R +F
}
```

`"$@"` will expand the arguments given. So you write `logsx service1 service2`.

Comment: This seems to run and remain running until hitting ctrl+c not display any of the logs ( which I am verifying are being produced in another terminal ).

Comment: Then that's probably an obstacle intrinsic to the union of `docker-compose` and `less`. Verify it by running `docker-compose logs -f service1 service2 | less -S -R +F` directly. It should behave likewise.

Comment: Yes, that I've verified works correctly.  Running that with or without the services specified works as I'd expect.

Comment: I think I probably has missed doing a `source` somewhere along the way when updating (despite trying to be sure I was doing that :-/ ), because now this is working fine for me.  Thanks!

Comment: For testing purposes, once edited and saved `.bashrc`, you may find it more convenient to simply open a new terminal instead of running `source .bashrc`. Anyway, glad to help!